# Hive or UNIX Output in Exponential E

Tags: unix, awk, sed, hive, printf

I have a hive query which generates the sum of a column in Exponential form `(3.52504582E+8)`. In SQL I am getting as numeric value from an RDBMS table. Both outputs I am writing to files and comparing the diff of the two files in UNIX for Validation check.

Is there a way to convert `3.52504582E+8` to `352504582` either in hive or at UNIX level so that validation succeeds?

Hive Table Sum: `3.52504582E+8`

RDBMS Table Sum: `352504582`

`diff <file1> <file2>` Validation failed.

Comment: but `352504582E8` is not equal to `352504582` at all

Comment: This is what Hive is writing to the text file. Is there a way to do that at UNIX level? 352504582E8 to 352504582

Comment: Hive supports "printf ()" since V0.9 so you can directly convert your sum into a String with whatever specific format you want. https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF

Comment: You the man, man. Thanks a lot. I fixed it easily and smartly at HIVE level. Thank you. 
Select printf("%.2f", sum(key_column)) from hive_table;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to convert 3.52504582E+8 to 352504582 either in hive or
>   at UNIX level sothat validation succeeds?

```
$ printf "%.f\n" 3.52504582E+8
352504582

$ awk '{print $1+0}' <<< "3.52504582E+8"
352504582

$ awk '{printf("%.f\n",$1)}' <<< "3.52504582E+8"
352504582
```

> I need to modify the result in the output file from Hive. Will the
>   above only print or make permanent changes? The file will have 2
>   fields and ~ separated. 262~3.52504582E+8

```
# if this is your input file
$ cat infile
262~3.52504582E+8

# result after
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="~"}{$2+=0}1' infile
262~352504582
```

**Explanation:**

- `FS` - input field separator, `OFS` - output field separator, we set both `FS` and `OFS` as `~`
- `$2+=0` awk converts automatically here
- `1` at the end does default operation that is print current/record/row, `print $0`. To know how awk works try, `awk '1' infile`, which will print all records/lines, whereas `awk '0' infile` prints nothing. Any number other than zero is *true*, which triggers the default behaviour.

Comment: I need to modify the result in the output file from Hive. Will the above only print or make permanent changes? The file will have 2 fields and ~ separated. 262~3.52504582E+8

Comment: Oh cool man. Thanks. Hope this works for my case. Thank you. I did not understand the second part though, the one within braces.

Comment: It worked. However for another case it did not. May be because it did not had '+' in it.
5.44321363987226E12 to 5443213639872.26